# Using Navigator in React Native

Tags: react-native, url-routing, navigator

I am using the Navigator component for React Native and so far so good, but ...

I can't seem to push() to the navigator from within the same component.  Here is an example:

```
updateNav(){
  navigator.push({page: 'newPage'});
}

render(){
  return (
    <Navigator initialRoute={{page: INITIAL_TAB}} />
  )
}
```

When I call

```
updateNav()
```

I get an error saying that 'navigator' is undefined.

Also, I can pass the navigator to children and update the Navigator from the children via 'props' with no problem.  But I have a case where I need to update the push to the Navigator from within the same component that has the Navigator component.

Answer (score 1):

The navigator is a property that you pass down to your scenes, so it won't be available in the same component you're rendering Navigator. I ran into this issue too and just moved up the Navigator to a higher component and made the current one the initial route.

Comment: Thanks, do you know of any examples using two navigators?  I am using one to control main pages and inside one of my main pages I have a sub navigator to control tabs on the page.

Answer (score -1):

I think navigator should be on your props

`this.props.navigator`